# kdb/q functional update for "prev 5 mavg col1"

Tags: kdb

How do i write functional update for below? instead of spelling out each column (of 0, 1, 2, 3 ... ) because there are a lot of them.

```
table: update pma0: prev 5 mavg fa_0, pma1: prev 5 mavg fa_1, pma2: prev 5 mavg fa_2, pma3: prev 5 mavg fa_3, pma4: prev 5 mavg fa_4 by sym from table
```

It's particularly difficult for me because "mavg" is not really a "function" I call like like mavg[a;b] and there is another function "prev" ahead of it.

I can't even figure out an **easier version of the problem**. if I just want to

```
table: update pma0: prev fa_0, pma1: prev fa_1, pma2: prev fa_2, pma3: prev fa_3, pma4: prev fa_4 by sym from table
```

below apparently didn't work. It gives me the same values for newCols and origCols.

```
ttt2: ![table; (); enlist[`ric]!enlist[`ric]; newCols!({prev; x} each origCols)]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example table to your question?

Comment: Functional query to create `ttt2` looks fine, probably there is an issue with values (value types) in `newCols` or `origCols`. Are they lists of symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use functional form similar to following

```
table: ![table;();(1#`sym)!1#`sym;(`$"pma",/:string til 5)!{(prev;(mavg;5;x))} each `$"fa_",/:string til 5];
```

Where `` (`$"pma",/:string til 5) `` creates list column names. And `` {(prev;(mavg;5;x))} each `$"fa_",/:string til 5 `` creates list of corresponding column values in functional form

Comment: thanks, the paranthesis inside `{(prev;(mavg;5;x))} each` is what I was missing.